# what is the correct way to make signup Auth and store it in database?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I have three screens:

1. Sign Up
2. log In
3. HomePage

now, In signup, I have some text field and a profile picture to store.
my question is how and what is the correct way to store data from the signup screen and then use the data to authenticate in the login screen.

Currently, I m using a realtime database from firebase to store data and email and password authenticate.
but rules for the realtime database is this:

```
{
"rules": {
".read": true,
".write": true
  }
}
```

but I want to use this rule:

```
{
"rules": {
".read": "auth != null",
".write": "auth != null"
   }
}
```

tell me what is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this link [Authenticate with Firebase using Password-Based Accounts on Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth)

The best approach is when a user signs up. You do it with the above code.
After the first authentication success.

You can use the FIrebaseUser.getUId to get the specific users unique identifier and use it as the user's key in a database.

In your databaseRerence you can save the user's data like the following.

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(FirebaseUser.getUID).setValue(USERDATA)
```

The USERDATA here is a pojo representing the user's data e.g. name,address,telephone etc

I always structure my apps in a way that am in control of the userflow.

1. have a splash screen that opens when a user opens my app, the i check if the user was already authenticated in an earlier process.
2. If firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser returns an object, i know that the user is registered and is already logged in so i will forward him to the Homepage.
3. If it returns null then i know the user might have logged out or not signed up. In that case i just send him to a login screen in your case log in.
4. if there weren't signed up they will not be able to proceed to HOmepage so you redirect
   them to the Sign up screeen.

Hope that helps. If you don't succeed with this approach. Don't worry the community got you.

Comment: one more question:
I have a profile pic in sign up screen, storing in firebase storage should I need to store ref of that pic in the database also?